# PHP showing error on the another page

Tags: php, regex, validation

This is my script. I want to print error when fields are empty and also when it does not match regex. But the error is showing on another page when I submit the form. I want to show the error on the same page below the form fields respectively.

```
<?php 

    //Connects to your Database 
     mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
     mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error()); 


     //Checks if there is a login cookie
     if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))


     //if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page
     { 
        $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 

        $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];

            $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());

        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  
            {
            if ($pass != $info['password']) 

                {
                            }
            else
                {

                header("Location: members.php");
                }
            }
     }


     //if the login form is submitted 

     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted



     // makes sure they filled it in

        if(!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass']) {

            die('You did not fill in a required field.');

        }

        // checks it against the database

        if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

            $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);

        }

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());

     //Gives error if user dosen't exist

     $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

     if ($check2 == 0) {

            die('That user does not exist in our database. <a href=add.php>Click Here to Register</a>');
                    }

     while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))     
     {

     $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);

        $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);

        $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);

     //gives error if the password is wrong

        if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']) {

            die('Incorrect password, please try again.');

        }
     else 
     { 

     // if login is ok then we add a cookie 

    $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
    $hour = time() + 3600; 
    setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['username'], $hour); 
    setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);   

    //then redirect them to the members area 
    header("Location: members.php"); 
     } 
    } 
    } 

    else 

    {    

     // if they are not logged in 

     ?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2><h1>Login</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="40">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="50">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<?php 

     } 

     ?>
```

I am a beginner. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Am new to stackoverflow also. So if my question is poor or not well formatted please suggest some tips.

Comment: You could send the form using javascript (AJAX). Use jquery and look into $.post() to get started :)

PS: do you mean same page? Or display errors without reloading the page?

Comment: same page.I also prefer without reloading.If you can help share your idea

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways for this.

1) If you only need validation done in PHP, then incase of error reshow the form too along with error message.

2) You can use Ajax for validation and show error if any without reloading page.

3) You can add javascript validation along with PHP(server) validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways:

**== EDIT ==**

*I didn't test any of this so some errors might occur :)*

With page reload:

Set the `action` attribute of the form to `''` or set it the the current page (or simply ommit it).

eg: `<form method="post" action="">`

This means that the page will reload when a user submits the form, but the data is sent to the same page the user was already on (in which case that's where your validation should be as well).

The second (a little more graceful way) is to use AJAX to send the form and show any errors based on the resultset. For this you'd probably want to use jQuery as it really simplifies sending form data and handling return values. You can get jQuery at http://jquery.com/.

The html:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <!-- Your inputs here -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit this form! />
</form>
```

This it what your JavaScript would look like (don't forget to include jQuery!):

```
$('#myFormId').submit(function(){

    // Submit the form using AJAX and expect a JSON return value
    $.post('my_validation_file.php', $(this).serialize(), function(result) {

        if (result != 'success') {
            // Set an error class on all fields that failed
            // according to our resultset
            for (var i in result) {
                $('[name="' + result[i] + '"]').addClass('error');
            }
        }
    }, 'json');

    // This prevents the form from submitting
    // and thus reloading your page!
    return false;
});
```

A simplified version of the PHP file and validation (note: php 5.4+ syntax!)

```
<?php

$errorFields = [];
$result = '';

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errorFields[] = 'email';
}

$result = count($errorFields) ? $errorFields : 'success';

die(json_encode($resrult));
```

Answer (score -1):

try putting `exit;` after all your `header` functions...